# Proving it is a unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$, Prove that if $v\in\mathbb{R^n}$ is a unit vector, then
$(v)_S$ is also a unit vector.

Any hints as to how I should prove that the coordinate vector is also a unit vector?

Comment: What is $v_s$ ?

Comment: i edited it accordingly, its meant to be $(v)_s$

Comment: still is unclear what is $(v)_s$

Comment: $v_S$ is presumably the coordinates of $v$ in the basis $S$.

Comment: yes it is the coordinates of v in the basis s

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\{e_{i}\,\vert\,i=1,\dots,n\}$. We have $$v_{S}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}e_{i}$$
then 
$$\begin{aligned}
\Vert v_{S}\Vert^{2} &=\left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}e_{i}\right\Vert^{2} &\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vert v_{i}\vert^{2}\Vert e_{i}\Vert^{2} &\text{(Pythagore)}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vert v_{i}\vert^{2} &\text{(}S\,\,\text{is orthonormal)}\\
&=1 &\text{(}v\,\,\text{is a unit vector)}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: In the notation of the OP, I think you would have $v = \sum v_i e_i$ and $(v)_S = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$; and the thing you are supposed to prove is that $\sum \left\lvert v_i \right\rvert^2 = 1$. But you are given that $\|v\|^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand you are asking if a vector that is unit in an orthonormal basis is  unit in all orthonormal basis.

This is a consequence of the fact that the transformation of coordinates between orthonormal basis is represented by [orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation) $T$, that are defined such that $\langle x,y\rangle =\langle Tu,Tv\rangle$, and these transformation are isometries that conserve lenght and angles.